# We are deploying java application in Google app engine and we are getting capacity error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, vision-api

We are deploying java application to use VisionAPI in Google app engine  and we are getting capacity error, we were asked to try with different zones still we are getting the same error,

GCLOUD: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [8] Flex operation projects/text-convert-304513/regions/us-east1/operations/6d4717fc-a5e9-419c-85cc-72394ed9e68a error [RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED]: An internal error occurred while processing task /app-engine-flex/insert_flex_deployment/flex_create_resources>2021-02-11T13:54:32.406Z50061.ue.1: The requested amount of instances has exceeded GCE's default quota. Please see https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas for more information on GCE resources.

Comment: What the quota exceeded? Do you have its name in the quota page?

Answer (score 0):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) the parameter 'max_num_instances', The maximum number of instances in your project should be 8 by default where I can see you may want to use more than that limit. I would like to suggest you to increase the [quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) limit for your project will solve the issue.

Comment: What is the name of the limit that applies here?